# Marketplace Support for Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

It seems since extensions were moved from Connect to Marketplace the Connect Manager is no longer showing available updates for extensions. Is there any way to keep using the Connect Manager or will I have to go through my extension manually to check for updates?